# Hibernate - maxElementsOnDisk from EHCache to TreeCache

Tags: java, hibernate, caching, ehcache

I'm migrating a Hibernate application's cache from EHCache to JBoss TreeCache.
I'm trying to find how to configure the equivalent to maxElementsOnDisk to limit the cache size on disk, but I couldn't find anything similar to configure in a FileCacheLoader with passivation activated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the version I am working on (JBossCache 1.4.1), it looks like it is not possible to configure this parameter.

Answer (score 2):

[This page](http://www.junlu.com/msg/179368.html) seems to imply that the correct configuration element is:

```
<attribute name="MaxCapacity">20000</attribute>
```

However, I've only ever used EHCache myself.

Comment: Thanks, but this parameter is not accepted anymore in the JBossCache version I'm working with (1.4.1)